# left outer join in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following two tables. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

```
Create table #tmp1 (
a char(1)
)

Create table #tmp2 (
id int,
a char(1),
val int
)

insert #tmp1 values ('A')
insert #tmp1 values ('B')
insert #tmp1 values ('C')

insert #tmp2 values (1,  'A', 10)
insert #tmp2 values (1,  'B', 20)
insert #tmp2 values (2,  'A', 30)
insert #tmp2 values (2,  'C', 40)

select * from #tmp1 t1 left outer join #tmp2 t2 on t1.a = t2.a
order by t2.id
```

This returns the result set

```
A   1   A   10
B   1   B   20
C   2   C   40
A   2   A   30
```

I would like to have the following result set

```
 A     1    A       10
 B     1    B       20
 C     1    null    null
 A     2    A       30
 B     2    null    null
 C     2    C       40
```

Right now i am acheiving this by creating a new table with a cross join like this and then doing a outer join

```
select * into #tmp3 from #tmp1 cross join (select distinct ID from #tmp2) t
select * from #tmp3 t1 left outer join #tmp2 t2 on t1.a = t2.a and t1.id = t2.id
```

Is there a better way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: The setup SQL is nice.  However, you should avoid "*"s in the queries, because it takes some deciphering to figure out which columns come from which tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get what you want, you need a "driving" table.  That is, you want a complete list of all combinations, and then to join to the other tables to get the matches.  Here is one way:

```
select t1.a, t2.*
from (select t1.a as a, t2.id as id
      from (select distinct a from #tmp1 t1) t1
           cross join
           (select distinct id from #tmp2 t2) t2
     ) driving left outer join
     #tmp1 t1
     on t1.a = driving.a left outer join
     #tmp2 t2
     on t2.id = driving.id and
        t2.a = driving.a
order by t2.id
```

Comment: Yes. I am doing something similar to what you are doing. I was hoping maybe there are some new SQL clauses like cross apply, outer apply etc that will make the code simpler.

Comment: Gordon has it right, you need to have a "driving" table in order to do this. We have code very similar to this to accomplish the same thing. There is nothing simple about making this type of query work.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a cartesian product of the values in #tbl1 and the values in the id column in #tbl2. Because the values in #tbl2.id are not unique it might be a better design to have an additional table with a row for each #tbl2.id value. Then you can use this solution:

```
Create table #tmp1 (
a char(1)
)

Create table #tmp2 (
id int,
a char(1),
val int
)

Create table #tmp3 (
id int
)

insert #tmp1 values ('A')
insert #tmp1 values ('B')
insert #tmp1 values ('C')

insert #tmp3 values (1)
insert #tmp3 values (2)

insert #tmp2 values (1,  'A', 10)
insert #tmp2 values (1,  'B', 20)
insert #tmp2 values (2,  'A', 30)
insert #tmp2 values (2,  'C', 40)

SELECT  t3.id,t1.a,t2.val
FROM    #tmp1 AS t1
CROSS JOIN #tmp3 AS t3
LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmp2 AS t2
ON t1.a = t2.a AND t3.id = t2.id
ORDER BY t3.id, t1.a;
```

If that is not an option use this instead:

```
SELECT  t3.id,t1.a,t2.val
FROM    #tmp1 AS t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM #tmp2) AS t3
LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmp2 AS t2
ON t1.a = t2.a AND t3.id = t2.id
ORDER BY t3.id, t1.a;
```